# Browsers unable to connect to Internet, other apps can, Parallels can

Tags: network, virtualization

This has been happening in the last few days: Chrome or Safari on the Mac (OSX Lion/10.7.2) are unable to connect to the Internet. Other apps are able to (Dropbox...). I am able to browse through IE on Win7 on Parallels. Terminal is able to `ping` to `www.google.com`.

I first thought it was a problem with Chrome, but Safari and Firefox have the same problem.

I am able to connect to the internet from my wife's laptop (Windows 7) and from my iPhone (over same WiFi network).

This problem gets resolved after I restart the Mac.

What can be wrong?

**Update**: When I use the IP address (`173.194.37.50` for `www.google.com`) I am able to reach Google, from Chrome. 
But even when I change the DNS to Google DNS, I still get the same issue when I use `www.google.com`. (This cannot be a DNS problem anyway right? `ping` is able to resolve `google.com` to its IP...)

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43066/browsing-to-a-nested-subdomain-resolves-wrong-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect a problem with the Parallels network driver, having seen similar issues before.  First, if you haven't already, try updating Parallels to the latest version.  Then, try changing the [networking mode](http://kb.parallels.com/4948) to Bridged, or if it already is, to Shared.  Also, here are [some generic troubleshooting steps](http://kb.parallels.com/5664).

[image: Screenshot of Parallels networking dialog]

Comment: Trying... but I am not sure whether this would be the root cause. I have Parallels for quite sometime now.

Comment: It looks like this *was* the problem. After I changed the setting (_Bridged_ to _Shared_), the problem never reoccurred. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have Parallels and have the exacy same problem.